# Is pathlength correction vital to be included while quantifying protein

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, zoology

I am trying to quantify protein in serum/plasma samples. I have carried out biuret assay for my samples using microplate reader. While performing I encountered the doubt whether I should include pathlength correction, blank subtraction steps to get accurate value. Why and how to use these factors for quantifying using microplate?

Comment: The exact way to take pathlength into account would probably depend on your platereader, though if you kept all wells at the same volume the pathlength should not be a problem. If you include blanks and a standard calibration curve on the plate, you should be able to work up the protein concentrations in your unknowns ok just using the absorption data directly from the plate reader. Just be sure to write down what well has what solution so you can do your spreadsheet correctly.